# Return embedded fields from Mongo group aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      value:{
        total: { $sum: "$value" },
        unique: { $sum: 1 }
       }  
    }
  },
  { $out : "test1" }
])
```

It's throwing error:

> "The field 'value' must be an accumulator object",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do it like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      total: { $sum: "$value" },
      unique: { $sum: 1}
    }
  },
  { $project: { _id: 1, value: {total: "$total", unique: "$unique"} } } 
])
```